# How to delay ng-keyup call in angular JS

Tags: angularjs

keyup in build directive of angular for filtering the record but I want to delay the function call so user can enter the full word and call can go to DB and fetch the record instead of single word. my line of code is

```
  <input ng-show="!$scope.noRPData" type="text" ng-keyup="filterRP($event)" class="filterRP form-control" id="txtFilterID" ng-model="rpFilter.ModifiedDate.value" />
```

filterRP is the function for which I want to delay the call by 4 second. Please suggest

Comment: why don't you think of adding `timeout` in you `filterRP()`

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend using `ng-change` instead of `ng-keyup`. You can than add the `ng-model-options` and configure the `debounce` time there. Then, your model will get changed only after this debounce time period has passed. See the [Debouncing updates](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions#debouncing-updates) docs section.

**UPDATE:**
Both `ng-change` and `$scope.$watch` should work with `ng-model-options` `debounce` option (in AngularJS v1.6.10). See this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/on4LM5pNtkrORgq1w4sw?p=preview)

Comment: added this line after your suggestion   <input ng-show="!$scope.noRPData" type="text" ng-change="filterRP($event)" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 4000 }" class="filterRP form-control" id="txtFilterRPDescription" ng-model="rpFilter.Description.value" /> its not working

Comment: Try using ``$scope.$watch`` instead of ``ng-change`` like this:    ``$scope.$watch('user.name', function() { ... });``, see this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/on4LM5pNtkrORgq1w4sw?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to delay it with `$timeout` (with additional if statement, to prevent calling every time a key is pressed). Then send some data within that timeout with `$http.post` request. Here is a simple demo that you can adopt for your example:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, $http) {
  var typing = false;
  $scope.filterRP = function(e) {
    if (!typing) {
      typing = true;
      $timeout(function() {
        typing = false;
        console.log("sending", $scope.x);
        /*
        var data = {"input":$scope.x}
        $http.post(url,data).
        then(function(response){
         // do something with response.data;
        },function(error){
         // log error
        });
        */
      }, 4000) // 4 second delay
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-keyup="filterRP($event)" ng-model="x" />
</div>
```

Comment: This is basically re-implementing the built-in `debounce` functionality.

Comment: @Thomas it's a more controlled version; if statements can be added for the additional logic, timeout can return a promise, etc.